# Server error / application with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure after changing to MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dll, asp.net-mvc-5

Recently we have updated MVC4 to MVC5. I have a webservice which used for reporting purpose when i launch the webservice i got the below errors

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Web.WebPages.PreApplicationStartCode.Start() +0
   System.Web.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode.Start() +37

[InvalidOperationException: The pre-application start initialization method Start on type System.Web.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..]
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +850
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods) +162
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +128
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +170
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +820

[HttpException (0x80004005): The pre-application start initialization method Start on type System.Web.Mvc.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +523
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +107
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +688
```

i have not referenced this **Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll** in my service but after upgrading to MVC5 got this dll issue. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

**Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll** is key library. You should add this one may be this one required / referenced internally.

You can check all dll ref in **packages.config** file and web.config 

 Or it may be present at local but you didn't make it **Copy Local to True in it's properties**